# CGFloats, floats getting set to zero

Tags: iphone, objective-c, getter-setter

I have a custom class Custom.mm in which I am trying to set a float value using a setter in my controller class MainController. The Custom instance is typed as an id because it is an Obj-C++ file and pointing to a proper class at compile time has worked well for me. Everything works fine, the instance is verified. If I set up the amount variable as type int and pass ints it works fine. Same with any other value or object--except floats. For some reason floats (float, CGFloat and the like) are set to 0 in the Custom.mm class. This is not an issue with NSLog or anything--I've checked the amount variable with a breakpoint and everything works but floats.

```
    //Custom.h
 @interface Custom : UIView  
{

      CGFloat amount;

}

 @property CGFloat amount;

 @end
```

---

```
    //Custom.mm
@implementation Custom
@synthesize  amount;

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder
{
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:coder])) 
    {
        //set initial value to 1
        self.amount = 1.0;  //verified as 1.0
    }
    return self;
}
```

---

```
    //MainController.h
@interface MainController : UIViewController 
{
    IBOutlet id customInstance; //IB points to the CustomView class
}
```

---

```
    //MainController.m
@implementation MainController

-(void)viewDidLoad
 {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        //Checking this value in Custom.mm via the debugger shows it as being 0, 
        //when before it was 1.0. 
        [customInstance setAmount:2.0]; 
  }

 @end
```

Comment: Can you share the actual source code that's failing? When exactly is the amount = 1 line being executed and how are you "checking this value in Custom.mm"?

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you use dot notation: `customInstance.amount = 2.0`?

Comment: @drewh amount = 1 gets set at initialization. I check the values using the debugger as well as logging.

Comment: @Ken I cannot use dot notation due to my setup--using Obj-C++ my customInstance is just an id at compile time, so I must use the setter (read: messaging) to set the value so that it connects up at runtime.

Comment: What you have written here is woefully insufficient to tell what's going on. If we actually ran the code you've given us, the `amount = 5` line would be setting a global variable, not an instance variable, since it's outside the context of the method.

Comment: I'll add more code--I just put this up to simply show what's going on. I have checked the value of amount, and confirmed that it is being set properly in the self.amount = 1 line. Setting it via the setAmount method in the controller class sets it to zero.

Comment: you said id points to CustomView class, where you defined a Custom class. Is it a typo? And is it a property? It has to be a property

Comment: Where in the code are you checking this value after setting?  My guess is that you forgot to hook up the IBOutlet, so customInstance is nil.

Comment: @nava no, it's not a property. It could be, but doesn't have to be. I guess it's just a global var in this case.

Comment: It is typed as an id because it's Obj-C++. It is hooked up properly. It works fine. Other methods are called just fine. All I am saying, is passing a float to it sets the float to 0 every time. It's the only issue I've had and I'm stumped.

Comment: It is something to do with floats. If I set the amount property up as an int, I can pass ints properly. When it's a float, it gets set to 0.

Comment: Something else I tried was setting up an NSNumber object and putting my float value within that and extracting it out. That worked fine as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this on my own; you've run into an interesting phenomenon.

Your problem is that the compiler can't see a definition for the `setAmount:` method. As a result, it doesn't know the correct type of the arguments that method is expecting. In such cases, the compiler assumes that all parameters are of type '...', and return values are of type 'id'. But you're passing a CGFloat, not a '...'.

Objective-C is a dynamic language, so even when the compiler doesn't know whether the target method exists, it will happily package up the parameters and try to call it anyway. **However**, on most architectures the method for passing parameters is dependent on the type of the parameters. Integers and pointer parameters are usually passed in one set of registers, while floating point parameters are passed in another, and structs are usually passed directly on the stack. (Precise details depend on which architecture you're running on.) Since the compiler can't see the definition for the `setAmount:` method, it assumes that the parameters are of type `...`. Depending on the architecture, those may be passed in a different set of registers, or even on the stack.

When the `setAmount:` method runs, however, it is expecting the passed-in parameters to be in a certain set of registers. Those weren't populated by the caller, of course, and are thus still set to 0. The caller put the new value in one location, but the receiver looked in another. No wonder things are going wrong.

**The solution to this is simple: Add `#import "Custom.h"` at the top of `MainController.m`.** Then, the compiler will be able to see the definition of `setAmount:` when it's compiling `MainController`, and will thus know to put the new values in the place that the receiver is expecting them.

Incidentally, I'll bet that when you were compiling, you were getting a warning; something like

```
warning: no '-setAmount:' method found
warning: (Messages without a matching method signature
warning: will be assumed to return 'id' and accept
warning: '...' as arguments.)
```

At least, that's the warning I'm getting. That was the compiler telling you that it didn't know where to put the parameters when making that call, so it just picked something and hoped it worked. In this case, it didn't.

As for ints and other types working correctly, the compiler's guess at the parameter passing style just happened to match what the receiver was expecting. It was a simple matter of luck.

Comment: Interesting. That does sound likely. Thanks for investigating this. I would agree that importing Custom.h and going about it the normal way would work. However, I've not found a solution since it is an objective c++ file (.mm), which requires me to make all files that import it into an objective c++ file--I was having compiler issues in XCode which had me use my current method.

Comment: If you can hide all the c++-ness from the .h file when compiling plain ObjC files, then you can still import the header into plain ObjC files without problems. You can do it either by using #ifdef \_\_cplusplus in the ObjC header or by hiding C++ ivar objects in an opaque struct. Then you only need to have a struct pointer in the header, which doesn't require any C++. If you need further help, it would be worth asking a separate question.

Comment: Of note: `CGFloat` is defined as `float` on iOS (and on Mac OS X, on 32-bit architectures). If you set the property type as `double`, it will work, because it will be receiving the same type you pass in (`1.0` is a `double`, not a `float`).

Comment: Also, if you set the property type as `unsigned long long` and pass `1`, that will fail, because while both are integers, `1` is an `int` and `unsigned long long` is bigger than `int`, requiring different calling conventions. It'd be the same problem.

Comment: @Peter: even when I explicitly declared the variable as a float before passing it in, I was still able to reproduce it. Floating point values (including doubles) are passed in a fundamentally different location; even if the size matches, the value will simply be in the wrong place.

Comment: @BJ Homer: Did you try explicitly declaring it as `double`? That's what I suggested would work. (I'm reconsidering that, though—I'm pretty sure `...` arguments all go on the stack, not in registers.)

Comment: Thanks to everyone, especially BJ Homer. I finally understood how to use #ifdef __cplusplus macros, and it works beautifully now. I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: @Peter Hosey: tested; defining the property as double makes no difference. And yes, it does also fail with unsigned long long.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't assigned a Custom object to the MainController's `customInstance` variable, so it's nil. Ask nil for anything and it will give you 0.

Comment: Thanks for looking. I stated that the instance gets set up at compile time via Interface Builder. It is not nil, and works fine. Literally everything else works perfectly. The only issue here is passing floats.